# How To Delete A Row In Excel Sheet Using Python?

Tags: python, excel, selenium, openpyxl

I am working on a `Selenium` program using `Python` where I want to delete a row in the `Excel` sheet using `Openpyxl` library. The issue is I don't know how to implement the delete function in my program. Below here have 2 classes, `AutoTest.py` which is the testing class and `NewCard.py` which is the class where I implemented `POM(Page Object Model)`. May I know how to implement the function to delete just 1 row in accordance with my program?

**AutoTest.py**

```
import unittest
import HtmlTestRunner
from selenium import webdriver
import openpyxl
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Users\lukegoh\Desktop\Python Projects\SoftwareAutomationTesting")
from pageObjects.LoginPage import LoginPage
from pageObjects.HomePage import Homepage
from pageObjects.NewCard import NewCard

excpath = r"C:\Users\lukegoh\Desktop\Python Projects\SoftwareAutomationTesting\excel\new\ABT0475EC Card Init Detailed Rpt Test 01 - v13_1.xlsx"
excsheetName = "ABT0475EC Card Initialization D"

class AutoTest(unittest.TestCase):
    baseURL = "https://10.2.5.215:33000/viewTopUpRequest"
    username = "ezltest2svc"
    password = "Password123!"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver.get(cls.baseURL)
        cls.driver.maximize_window()
        cls.driver.implicitly_wait(10)


    def test_1(self):  #This is scenario 1- to create request for new card
        lp = LoginPage(self.driver)
        hp = Homepage(self.driver)
        np = NewCard(self.driver)
        lp.setUsername(self.username)
        lp.setPassword(self.password)
        lp.clickLogin()
        hp.clickutil()
        hp.clickreqNewCard()
        np.setJobOrder()
        np.clickExcel()
        np.setTopUpAmount()
        np.calculateAmount()
        if not np.clickSubmit():
            np.deleteRow(excpath,excsheetName,3)
        else:
            print("Test Passed")


   # @classmethod
   # def tearDownClass(cls):
   #     cls.driver.close()
   #     print("Test Completed")


#if __name__ == '__main__':
#    unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='C:/Users/lukegoh/Desktop/Python Projects/SoftwareAutomationTesting/reports'))
```

**NewCard.py**

```
import openpyxl

class NewCard:

    jobOrder_xpath="//body/div[@id='wrapper']/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/input[1]"
    excelButton_xpath="//input[@id='img']"
    topup_textbox_xpath="//input[@id='input-live']"
    calculateAmount_xpath="(//button[@type='button'])[4]"
    buttonSubmit_xpath="(//button[@type='button'])[5]"


    def __init__(self,driver):
        self.driver=driver


    def setJobOrder(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.jobOrder_xpath).send_keys("AutoTest1")

    def clickExcel(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.excelButton_xpath).send_keys(r"C:\Users\lukegoh\Desktop\Python Projects\SoftwareAutomationTesting\excel\new\ABT0475EC Card Init Detailed Rpt Test 01 - v13_1.xlsx")

    def setTopUpAmount(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.topup_textbox_xpath).send_keys("10")

    def calculateAmount(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.calculateAmount_xpath).click()

    def clickSubmit(self):
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(self.buttonSubmit_xpath).click()

    def deleteRow(file, sheetName, rownum):
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
        sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheetName)
        sheet.cell(row=rownum).
        workbook.save(file)
```

Comment: This is covered in the openpyxl documentation. Is there anything there you don't understand?

Comment: why the downvote? I didn't do anything that's insufficient in terms of the information presented

Comment: You appear not to have read the documentation.

Comment: I did but I had trouble figuring out how to do it since it's my maiden attempt in Python though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check OpenPyXL docs, it has something called `delete_rows()`

Syntax `delete_rows(idx, amount=1)`, it deletes from `idx` and goes on deleting for `amount`

```
import openpyxl

filename = "example.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
sheet = wb['Sheet1']
sheet.delete_rows(row_number, 1)
wb.save(filename)
```

Docs for `delete_rows()`: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.delete_rows

Answer (score -3):

use pandas

```
 import pandas as pd
 df = pd.read_excel("test.xlsx")
 df = df.drop(df.index[1])
 df.to_excel('test1.xlsx')
```

Comment: OP is using openpyxl, not Pandas. Why should they install a new, fairly large library just to delete a row? Surely openpyxl can handle that?

Comment: Thanks @Chris . I only suggested pandas because it is more famous and stronger and given that in the title of the question asked "how to delete a row in Excel".

Comment: Thanks @TomerShetah. Next time I will be more careful in answering the questions.

Comment: I see. Please read the question as well as the title. There should necessarily be additional useful information there; it can't all fit in the title. And please pay particular attention to the question's _tags_. This one is explicitly tagged with the [tag:openpyxl] tag.

Comment: Thanks @Chris.  I will pay attention to the points you said